# Angular - How to navigate to a different component from the same named router outlet

Tags: angular

I have an app which has a side nav bar, the content of the side nav bar is filled using a named router outlet "aside".

There is a list-component associated with the aside side nav. This component contains a list of items. A user can click a list to go to the detailed version. The detailed version should replace the list-component in the same named router outlet aside.

**routing.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ReportsComponent
    },
    {
        path: ':id',
        component: ReportDetailComponent,
        resolve: {
            job: JobResolver,
            report: ReportResolver,
            activity: ActivityResolver,
        },
        children: [
            { path: 'top-words-aside', component: TopWordsAsideComponent, outlet: 'aside' },
            { path: 'top-words-detail-aside', component: TopWordsDetailAsideComponent, outlet: 'aside' },
        ]
    }
];
```

Here i am trying to open the detail version

**top-words-aside-component.ts**

```
    showFullConversation() {
//close the current one
        this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { aside: null } }], { relativeTo: this.route.parent });
//open detailed versoin
        this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { aside: ['TopWordsDetailAsideComponent'] } }], { relativeTo: this.route.parent });

    }
```

Error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'reports/5a85d1cbcff47e0001e34640' Error: Cannot match
>   any routes. URL Segment: 'reports/5a85d1cbcff47e0001e34640'

Comment: you need to try dynamic component loading 
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Hmm interesting, the demo on there is broken do you have a better example i can look at. Would this allow me to go back to the previous list component?

Comment: Demo is working on my system, and this is the best way to switch screen

Comment: No, you need to maintain the log

Comment: This would mean i could get rid of the named router outlet all togeather? Also the live stackblitz example is not working.